# javascript slider has a wrong size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slider on that page:
http://en.expo.b24online.com/news/
The js for the silder is:
on the document ready:

```
$('#newsCarousel').carousel({
    interval:   4000
  }).on('click', '.list-group li', function() {
      clickEvent = true;
      $('.list-group li').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
  }).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
    if(!clickEvent) {
      var count = $('.list-group').children().length -1;
      var current = $('.list-group li.active');
      current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
      var id = parseInt(current.data('slide-to'));
      if(count == id) {
        $('.list-group li').first().addClass('active');
      }
    }
    clickEvent = false;
  });
```

and on the load:

```
var boxheight = $('#newsCarousel .carousel-inner').innerHeight();
var itemlength = $('#newsCarousel .item').length;
var triggerheight = Math.round(boxheight/itemlength+1);
$('#newsCarousel .list-group-item').outerHeight(triggerheight);
$('.media-img').height(boxheight);
```

It works fine on some places, but on this website, I have the:

```
$('#newsCarousel .carousel-inner').innerHeight();
```

to be 133, and this makes all the other dimensions calculate in the load function wrong.
I couldn't find where this 133 come from and how to fix it.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why do you think that is a javascript issue and not a css one?

Comment: checked all the css, I saw nothing there, can you see the problem there?

Comment: some files return 404 check their links !!$

Comment: I haven't finished with the site building, I want to solve the news slider problem

Answer (score 0):

`.innerHeight()` method is not applicable to `window` and `document` objects; for these, use `.height()` instead.

eg:

```
$('#newsCarousel .carousel-inner').height();
```

Hope it will help.